# Windows 8 universal app ASP.Net web Api

Tags: asp.net, windows, store

I'm trying binding image from ASP.NET Web Api service  there i have contorller

```
public class ImageController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage GetImage()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream("FileAddress", FileMode.Open));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        return response;
    } 
}
```

client side is Windows 8 universal app there are next code

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri datauri = new Uri("http://localhost:63606/Api/Image");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var datafil = await client.GetAsync(datauri);
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, datauri);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(randomAccessStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
}
```

I don't know what to do , I couldn't get image for example in BitmapImage file.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second way if you want get many photo  is that you can create new folder in API folder and named it for example PhotoRepository add photo in this folder and get photo via it URI

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Uri datauri = new Uri("http://localhost:63606/PhotoReposytory/"photo name".jpg"); 
//jpg  or other format
                BitmapImage foto = new BitmapImage(datauri);
                Image1.Source = foto;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

inYou can do the following

```
public class ImageController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage GetImage()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream("FileAddress", FileMode.Open));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        return response;
    } 
}
```

and in the WinRt app write following code

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri datauri = new Uri("Api Uri");
            BitmapImage image= new BitmapImage(datauri);
            // if you want show result in XAML Controls 
            Image1.Sourse=image;
        }
```

in XAML

```
 <Image x:Name="Image1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="292" Margin="48,413,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310"/>
```